# Как отображать иконки в контекстном меню?

Tags: android, java

Переопределил метод `onCreateContextMenu` у наследника `ListFragment` вот так:

```
@Override 
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo info) { 
  super.onCreateContextMenu(contextMenu, view, info); 
  contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Test"); 
  contextMenu.add("Example"); 
}
```

Но нашел только методы, позволяющие создавать контекстное меню только с текстом. А как сделать, чтобы можно было представить пункт меню как `ImageView` + `TextView`? В интерфейса 
[`android.view.Menu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html), кажется, нет никакой возможности для этого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контекстные меню на андроиде нативно не поддерживают иконки, см. [**документацию:**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)

> Note: Context menu items do not support icons or shortcut keys.

*Но, как всегда, недостающую функциональность можно заэмулить самостоятельно*, как это делается, можно посмотреть [**в этом референсе.**](http://www.tanisoft.net/2010/09/android-context-menu-with-icon.html)